# What do the symbols in database grids mean?

Tags: database, delphi, grid

Looking at the selected row in a database-linked grid, sometimes I see a small black triangle, other times I see an I-beam. (In the screenshot below, there's an I-beam next to the row displaying "Results/Findings.") What's the difference between the meaning of these symbols? (Are there other symbols?)

Thanks, as always.

[image]

Comment: Link please, or image if possible. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Where is there a "small black triangle"? And what "database" is this (or rather, what software is this)?

Comment: Software is homemade, using Delphi. The "small black triangle" would mark a selected record/row. Only one record/row can be selected at a time, so I can't post a screenshot with both symbols present.

Comment: So, this is how you view the database in Delphi? Or in a Delphi database-linked grid?

Comment: The latter ... screenshot is executable program, originally created in Delphi.

Comment: Why not consult the documentation on the control - that should give you an indication. Chances are the black triangle means that not all text shows and clicking it will reveal more. The IBeam would probably mean that you can start editing the values. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Black triangle indicates the current row. The I-beam looking symbol means you are editing the record. If you see an asterisk icon, it means you are inserting a record.